# Getting an error in putting the name of the file from a folder after the last filled column

Tags: vba, excel

Previous question regarding the syntax has been solved by Scott for putting in the name of the file to the master workbook. Slightly modified new question

Essentially, i have hundreds of files in a folder and i am copying all the data from those files to a master workbook to the tabs where both the source and destination tab names match. Everything runs fine except putting in the name of the file next to the data that has been copied and the problem is, it is only filling the first row because it's the blank one which i think is because of the following line:

```
lLastRow = wsDst.UsedRange.Rows(wsDst.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row + 1
```

Here is the code. I am pretty sure there's a easy way of going on about doing this

```
Sub ProjectMacro()
Dim wbDst As Workbook
Dim wsDst As Worksheet
Dim wbSrc As Workbook
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Dim MyPath As String
Dim strFilename As String
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim lLastColumn As Long
Dim LC As Long
Dim s As Worksheet, t As String
Dim i As Long, K As Long
K = Sheets.Count


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set wbDst = ThisWorkbook
MyPath = "C:\Users\tomhardy\Desktop\787 files\"
strFilename = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls*", vbNormal)

Do While strFilename <> ""
'loop through each worksheet in the source file
For Each wsSrc In wbSrc.Worksheets
    'Find the corresponding worksheet in the destination with 
the same name as the source
  On Error Resume Next
Set wsDst = wbDst.Worksheets(wsSrc.Name)
    On Error GoTo 0
If wsDst.Name = wsSrc.Name Then
lLastRow = 
 wsDst.UsedRange.Rows(wsDst.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row + 1    
 lLastColumn =wsDst.UsedRange.Columns(wsDst.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column + 1
  wsSrc.UsedRange.Copy
 wsDst.Range("A" & lLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
 wsDst.Cells(1,lLastColumn).Value = wbDst.FullName
 End If
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next wsSrc


wbSrc.Close False
strFilename = Dir()
Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `wsDst.Range(1 & lLastColumn).Value` to `wsDst.Cells(1,lLastColumn).Value` because the way you have it written is not correcty syntax.

Comment: That works, thanks Scott. The only problem is, it is only filling the first row because it's the blank one which i think is because of the following line:    
 lLastRow = wsDst.UsedRange.Rows(wsDst.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row + 1

Comment: And i only want to show the file name next to each row that is copied

Comment: So, you can either edit your question to ask about the new error or make a new question. This question as is stands to be closed bc it was only a syntax issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this one.. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
wsDst.Cells(1,lLastColumn).Resize(wsSrc.UsedRange.Rows.Count,1).Value = wbDst.FullName
```

The code itself should be explanatory enough as to what it's doing.

Or this, because I am not 100% sure exactly what you want.

```
wsDst.Range("A" & lLastRow).Resize(wsSrc.UsedRange.Rows.Count,1).Value = wbDst.FullName
```

Comment: I kind of thought so @Piccinin :)